# Jump to a different switch case based on conditon, like a goto

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I need to move from one case to another case based on the condition. For example, this is my code:

```
switch (req.method) {
  case 'GET':
    alert('GET METHOD');
    break;
  case 'POST':
    alert('POST METHOD');
    break;
  case 'PUT':
    alert('PUT METHOD');
    break;
  default:
    res.end();
}
```

In the above code, in the `POST` case I need to check, for example `if(A === B)`, then go to the `PUT` case like that. How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make a conditional recursive

```
function checkMethod(method) {
    switch (method) {
        case 'GET':
            alert('GET METHOD');
            break;
        case 'POST':
            alert('POST METHOD');
            checkMethod('PUT'); // here stand the pros of a function
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            alert('PUT METHOD');
            break;
        default:
            res.end();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do that by removing the `break;`. If it reaches the end of the POST case, it will continue with the next case if there is no `break;`. [More Information on `switch fallthrough`](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/fallthrough.htm)

Example:

```
switch (req.method) {
 case 'GET':
       alert('GET METHOD');
       break;
 case 'POST':           
       alert('POST METHOD');
       if (A === B) {
           break;
       }
 case 'PUT':
       alert('PUT METHOD');
       break;
 default:
   res.end();
}
```